# Android ViewPager Nested Fragment Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I am using nested fragments and viewPager together. Following is my code for `HomeFragment` which is one of the fragments in viewPager. `HomeFragment` holds another fragment called `FeedFragment` which is just a `RecyclerView`. Inside `FeedFragment` I am using a callback interface which notifies `HomeFragment` that `FeedFragment` was successfully created. The problem I am having is, first time `HomeFragment` is created, `mListener` value is set to an instance of `HomeFragment` inside `onCreateView` and everything is loaded properly. When I move to a different fragment in viewPager and go back to `HomeFragment`, `HomeFragment` `onCreateView` method is called and `mListener` is again set to an instance of `HomeFragment` and after that `onCreateView` method is called from `FeedFragment` but `mListener` is `null` this time.

Following is the code for FeedFragment:

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView feedRecyclerView;
    FeedRecyclerViewAdapter feedRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private OnCompleteListener mListener;

    public FeedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

        feedRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.postFeedItemContainer);
        feedRecyclerViewAdapter = new FeedRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity());
        feedRecyclerView.setAdapter(feedRecyclerViewAdapter);
        feedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mListener.onComplete(feedRecyclerViewAdapter, this);

        return view;
    }

    public interface OnCompleteListener {
        void onComplete(
                FeedRecyclerViewAdapter feedRecyclerViewAdapter, FeedFragment feedFragment);
    }

    public void setmListener(OnCompleteListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }
}
```

Following is the code for HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements FeedFragment.OnCompleteListener {

    // presenter instance
    private HomeFragmentPresenter homeFragmentPresenter = HomeFragmentPresenter.getInstance();

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        FeedFragment feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
        feedFragment.setmListener(this);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentHomeFeedContainer, feedFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(FeedRecyclerViewAdapter feedRecyclerViewAdapter, FeedFragment feedFragment) {
        homeFragmentPresenter.fetchDataForAdapter(feedRecyclerViewAdapter, feedFragment);
    }
}
```